# .NET CLR Stored procedure OUTPUT Parameter

Tags: .net

I am creating a CLR stored procedure in VB.NET (.NET 3.5,SQLServer 2005). The procedure has 4 BYVal parameter and 4 BYRef parameters. It compiles and deploys correctly into SQL Server and a Stored procedure is created.
However when I try to run the SP it insists on passing the OUTPUT parameters in. It gives the following error

I am running it from SQL Server as Below

DECLARE @return_value int,
        @outI int,
            @outS nvarchar(4000),
            @outD datetime,
            @outB bit

```
EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[ProofOfConcept]
        @inI = 23,
        @inS = N'john',
        @inD = N'12/12/2009',
        @inB = 1,
        @outI = @outI OUTPUT,
        @outS = @outS OUTPUT,
        @outD = @outD OUTPUT,
        @outB = @outB OUTPUT
```

> 'TestProc' failed because parameter 5 is not allowed to be null.

My VB.NET procedure declaration is below

```
 Public Shared Sub TestProc(ByVal inI As Integer, ByVal inS As String, ByVal inD As DateTime, ByVal inB As Boolean, _
                                     ByRef outI As Integer, ByRef outS As String, ByRef outD As DateTime, ByRef outB As Boolean)
```

Comment: I think you forgot the paste in the error message.

Comment: In addition to @siride comment, how you are calling the stored procedure would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Out()` attribute before `ByRef` as in the code below

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
…
Public Shared Sub PriceSum ( <Out()> ByRef value As SqlInt32)
```